# Argument Error on update params - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

I am using the fullcalendar framework to create “Timeslots” on the calendar.  The time slots are associated with an “Experience”.  The problem I am running into is when I want to edit the time slot from the calendar.

FullCalendar has a method that allows for a callback when clicking on the event, and passes all the data for that event through.  I have built out an HTML form (not using rails form_for) so that I can inject the :id values directly into the form.

I can see in my rails console, and the error page, that all the parameters and id values are present on the page.  However, I can’t get pass this argument error which I believe is referencing that it is not receiving the id for the time slot?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**Rails Console Error**

```
    app/controllers/timeslots_controller.rb:30:in `update'
    Started PATCH "/experiences/3/timeslots/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:13:04 -0700
    Processing by TimeslotsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OKz4aA+GDK74dFRaO9p2WA+2fFKrKzrAAmkFLZAkgT4w0DNMPEcUpH7IJR6P/debkSjOBjkRqzBI1+nk8uvecA==", "timeslot"=>{"start_time"=>"2018-04-09 12:00 am", "end_time"=>"2018-04-09 12:00 am", "inventory"=>"4", "price"=>"120"}, "button"=>"", "experience_id"=>"3", "id"=>"16"}
      User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Timeslot Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "timeslots".* FROM "timeslots" WHERE "timeslots"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "timeslots"."start_time" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Experience Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "experiences".* FROM "experiences" WHERE "experiences"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      CACHE Timeslot Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "timeslots".* FROM "timeslots" WHERE "timeslots"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "timeslots"."start_time" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



    ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

    app/controllers/timeslots_controller.rb:30:in `update'
```

**timeslots_controller.rb**

```
    class TimeslotsController < ApplicationController

      before_action :set_timeslot, only: [:edit, :update]


      def create
        experience = Experience.find(params[:experience_id])

        start_time = Date.parse(timeslot_params[:start_time])
        end_time = Date.parse(timeslot_params[:end_time])

        @timeslot = current_user.timeslots.build(timeslot_params)
        @timeslot.price = experience.price
        @timeslot.experience = experience
        @timeslot.save

        flash[:notice] = "Timeslot created successfully!"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer, notice: "Timeslot created")
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /experiences/1
      # PATCH/PUT /experiences/1.json
      def update

        experience = Experience.find(params[:experience_id])
        @timeslot = Timeslot.find(params[:id])


        new_params = timeslot_params
        new_params = timeslot_params.merge

        if @timeslot.update(new_params)
          flash[:notice] = "Updated..."
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
        end

        redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
      end

      def edit

      end

      def reservations

      end

      private
        def timeslot_params
          params.require(:timeslot).permit(:inventory, :price, :start_time, :end_time)
        end

        def set_timeslot
          @timeslot = Timeslot.find(params[:id])
        end

    end
```

**host.html.erb**

```
    <% if !@experiences.blank? %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Your Timeslot Manager</h2>
            <p>This is your host calendar where you can add timeslots.</p>
            <%= link_to "Back to Dashboard", hosting_dashboard_path, class: "btn btn-geoguides-o" %>
          </div>
        <%= search_form_for @search, class: "form-group", url: host_calendar_path do |f| %>
          <div class="col-md-12 select" style="top: 25px;">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Your Experiences</label>
              <%= f.select :experience_id, options_for_select(@experiences.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id] if u.published?}.compact, params[:experience_id]), {}, {
                onchange: "$(this.form).submit()",
                class: "form-control"
                } %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :start_time, id: "start_time", value: params[:start_time], onchange: "$(this.form).submit()" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <%= render 'form' %>
      <%= render 'editform' %>

    <% end %>
    </div>

    <hr/><br/>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="calendar">

      </div>
    </div>



    <script>
      window.timeslots = <%= raw @events.to_json %>
      console.log(timeslots);



      function showTimeslots(data) {
        return data.map(function (e) {




          return {
            name: e.fullname,
            inventory: e.inventory,
            timeslot: e.id,
            price: e.price,
            start_time: e.start_time,
            end_time: e.end_time,
            start: e['start_time'],
            end: e['end_time']
          }
        })
      }

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,prev,next'
        },
        defaultDate: $('#start-time').val(),
        editable: true,
        events: showTimeslots(timeslots),
        eventClick: function(event){
          if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
          }

          console.log(event.timeslot);
          console.log(event.start_time);
          console.log(event.end_time);

          var experience = '<%= j @experience.id.to_s %>';

          console.log(experience);





          $('#timeslot_id').val(event.timeslot);

          $('#edit_calendar').modal('show');

          $("#edit_timeslot").attr("action", "/experiences/" + experience + "/timeslots/" + event.timeslot);


          var start = moment(event.start_time).tz('UTC').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');
          var end = moment(event.end_time).tz('UTC').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');

          console.log(start);

          $('#timeslot_edit_start_time').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate: start,
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            showTimezone: false,
            timezoneList: [
                                { value: 0, label: 'UTC'}
                            ]
          });

          $('#timeslot_edit_end_time').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate: end,
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            showTimezone: false,
            timezoneList: [
                                { value: 0, label: 'UTC'}
                            ]
          });

          $('#timeslot_edit_start_time').val(moment(event.start_time).tz('UTC').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
          $('#timeslot_edit_end_time').val(moment(event.end_time).tz('UTC').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
          $('#timeslot_edit_inventory').val(event.inventory);
          $('#timeslot_edit_price').val(event.price);


        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

          var eventsdate = new Date(event.start_time);
          var eventedate = new Date(event.end_time);

          var e_start_time = moment(eventsdate);
          var e_end_time = moment(eventedate);

          var userTZ = moment.tz.guess();

          console.log(moment(event.start_time).tz('UTC').format('h:mm A Z'));


          var e_S_Clean = moment(event.start_time).tz('UTC').format('h:mm A');
          var e_E_Clean = moment(event.end_time).tz('UTC').format('h:mm A');

          return $(`
            <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end">
              <div class="fc-content">
                <span class="fc-title">
                    <span>${e_S_Clean} - ${e_E_Clean} </span><br/>
                    Spaces: ${event.inventory} | Price: $${event.price}

                <span/>
              <div/>
            <a/>
            `);
        },
        /*dayRender: function(date, cell){
          <% if !@experiences.blank? %>
            cell.append('<span class="day-price">' + '$<%= @experience.price %>' + '</span>')
          <% end %>
        },*/
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {

          <% if @experiences.blank? %>
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
          <% end %>

          $('#new_calendar').modal('show');

          var start_date = moment(start);
          var end_date = moment(end).subtract(1, "days");




          $('#timeslot_start_time').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate: start_date.format("yy-mm-dd hh:mm"),
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            showTimezone: false,
            timezoneList: [
                                { value: 0, label: 'UTC'}
                            ]
          });

          $('#timeslot_end_time').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate: end_date.format("yy-mm-dd hh:mm"),
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            showTimezone: false,
            timezoneList: [
                                { value: 0, label: 'UTC'}
                            ]
          });

          $('#timeslot_start_time').val(start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a"));
          $('#timeslot_end_time').val(end_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a"));



        }
      });


      $('.fc-prev-button').click(function(){
        var current = new Date($('#start-time').val());
        var prev = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() - 1, 1)
        $('#start-time').val(moment(prev).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        $('#start-time').trigger('change')
      });

      $('.fc-next-button').click(function(){
        var current = new Date($('#start-time').val());
        var next = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() + 1, 1)
        $('#start-time').val(moment(next).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        $('#start-time').trigger('change')
      });




    </script>
```

**_editform.html.erb**

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="edit_calendar">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="edit_timeslot" id="edit_timeslot" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="f2j0yxOJBXZQ78egS5ZbKHuepV2L2+S6U37TfRdvFVh3FD/vIEgdfNZTtuT/sfrr5QAXCRnhdUoZwD+0daBKFg==">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input readonly="readonly" value="2018-04-01" class="form-control datetimepicker hasDatepicker" style="cursor: pointer;" type="text" name="timeslot[start_time]" id="timeslot_edit_start_time">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input readonly="readonly" value="2018-04-01" class="form-control datetimepicker hasDatepicker" style="cursor: pointer;" type="text" name="timeslot[end_time]" id="timeslot_edit_end_time">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                        <input placeholder="How many people can come?" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="timeslot[inventory]" id="timeslot_edit_inventory">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p style="margin-top: 10px">Inventory</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row new-pricing">
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input class="form-control" value="120" required="required" type="text" name="timeslot[price]" id="timeslot_edit_price">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p style="margin-top: 10px">Per Booking</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="no-pricing hide">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
      </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>






      <script>

      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
      }

      });

        $(function() {
          var notAvailable = $('#calendar_status_not_available'),
              available = $('#calendar_status_available');

          notAvailable.click(function() {
            $('.no-pricing').show();
            $('.new-pricing').hide();
          });

          available.click(function() {
            $('.no-pricing').hide();
            $('.new-pricing').show();
          });
        });
      </script>



      <script>

      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
      }

      });

        $(function() {
          var notAvailable = $('#calendar_status_not_available'),
              available = $('#calendar_status_available');

          notAvailable.click(function() {
            $('.no-pricing').show();
            $('.new-pricing').hide();
          });

          available.click(function() {
            $('.no-pricing').hide();
            $('.new-pricing').show();
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: What's this `timeslot_params.merge` supposed to do?

Comment: To be honest I’m not entirely sure :/, I’m still new to Rails and am a bit unclear on the update action.  I believe it’s supposed to merge the new params from the form into the DB?  If I remove it, I’m still getting the same errors...

Comment: I take that back!  When I removed the .merge in the controller, the update now works correctly.  Any idea what that’s all about?

Comment: So I think I’ve worked out what was going on.  When passing the .merge command, Ruby Docs say it needs to compare the first set of params against the second set.  Since the first set is already loaded, the only argument that needs to be provided would be a second set.  Since I’m not trying to actively merge those two, and have already fed the data from the original params hash into the form, I can remove that merge and just run the update normally.

Comment: You can just use `timeslot_params` as you're creating a variable just to store its value. `merge` is for "joining" hashes, so clearly, you needed the second hash, that's intended to be passed through the arguments.